# Объясните как гнуть svg слои с помощью js кода?

Tags: javascript, svg

Я нашел библиотеку warp.js которая позволяет гнуть svg файлы.

Но я так и не понял как это сделать в документаций есть только два примера и общее описание функций.

https://github.com/benjamminf/warpjs

Как в

```
 const svg = document.getElementById('svg-element')
 const warp = new Warp(svg)

 warp.interpolate(4)
 warp.transform(([ x, y ]) => [ x, y + 4 * Math.sin(x / 16) ])
```

Установить свои значения а если точнее то - я просто хочу создать массив опорных точек с параметрами.

```
arr = [
  [x=0,y=0,r=10,p=10, n[x=10,y=10]],
  [x=10,y=10,r=10,p=10, n[x=10,y=10]]
]
```

где

```
x=положение по вертикали,
y=положение по горизонтали,
r=радиус воздействия
p=жесткость воздействия
n=направление движения по которому идет воздействие
```

Если установлена другая статична опорная точка то она будет удерживать часть фигуры на своем месте.

Примерно как в марионеточной деформаций (Puppet Warp)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто ни будь может мне объяснить по какому принципу код работает?

Особенно мне не понятно что находится внутри X и Y и как я должен ориентироваться что бы исказить свой svg файл как мне нужно?

Я не очень хорош в геометрии поэтому можете объяснить как можно подробнее.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Костя, ты наверное уже посмотрел этот вопрос, но на всякий случай пишу. Вдруг захочется тебе ответить.  Было бы интересно посмотреть.

Comment: math любой работает [из этой инструкции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) в квадратных скобках можно прибавлять и отнимать то есть тем самым мы смещаете точку деформации то есть если к примеру обернуть в группу отдельно любой элемент то можно добиться следующего https://i.ibb.co/FWBpBFQ/warp.png

Comment: @MaximLensky Вы просто сказали что можно воздействовать на отдельные слои и то что код использует Объект Math. Но я так и не понял что означает `X` `Y` `OY` и так далее и как сделать то что я задумал. хотя бы в общих чертах